# DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'usesqlserver' and no extension method 'usesqlserver' in asp.net core 2.2?

Tags: asp.net-core

project version : .netcore2.2

I m working With N-Tier Architecture in .netcore2.2

when I defining below configuration then give the error:

**DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'usesqlserver' and no extension method 'usesqlserver'**

```
    public class CustomerDataAccess : DbContext, ICustomerDataAccess
    {

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder dbContextOptionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!dbContextOptionsBuilder.IsConfigured && _configuration.GetConnectionString("DMEBaseConnection") != null)
            {
                dbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("connectionstringname")); **//here give an error**
            }
        }
```

startup.cs

```
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
        }
    }
```

program.cs

```
namespace projectname
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

see below image:

[image]

when I install this:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 2.2.6
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 3.1.2
```

Current Error:

```
NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0 requires Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (>= 2.2.0 && < 2.3.0) but version Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.1.2 was resolved.

projectname-> projectname.BusinessLogic -> projectname.DataAccess -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 3.1.2) 
 projectname-> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 2.2.0 && < 2.3.0).
```

I m trying to solve this error last midday but error not solved

plz, help?

Comment: From [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-2/#getting-ef-core-2.2), EF Core 2.2 is as part of ASP.NET Core 2.2 and the new .NET Core SDK. As long as you have the corresponding Asp.net core SDK 2.2 installed, press **Alt + Enter** to add the corresponding assembly according to the prompts when using `UseSqlServer()`.

Comment: And there is a yellow warning triangle on the Packages of Dependencies , this is an explicit decision to indicate to the user that the restore has not yet completed for this project.

Answer (score 5):

Install the nuget package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Comment: What is the issue when I install this plugin plz help?

Comment: @Rahul That error tells you the exact problem - use the correct version. Try this: `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 2.2.6`

Comment: @DavidG again give an error ```Install-Package : NU1107: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. Install/reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.2 directly to the project to resolve this issue. 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 3.1.2) 
 DMEBase -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 2.2.0 && < 2.3.0).```

Comment: @DavidG when I try this again give an error```Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 3.1.2```

Answer (score 1):

Install the nuget package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

And put this directive in your class:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Without the directive or the nuget package it doesn't work